# Match Two Tables Rows Together in Excel

Tags: excel

I have two tables on one spreadsheet, I need to set up the second table(RHS) so that its volcano numbers correspond to the same row as the same volcano number from the first table(LHS) (highlighted red). This first table also contains duplicates as highlighted in green. It would be preferable to duplicate the corresponding row of the data from the second table with it.
[image: Excel Spreadsheet with two tables, one of which is highlighted, the duplicate volcano numbers correspond with the green highlights]

Comment: Can someone explain why this is getting downvoted?

Comment: Maybe coz you didn't share what you had tried..  |  btw, if both table is having the same data.. just sort both table separately by Volcano no., then combine.